# Motor for DIY Remote controlled shades

Tags: blinds

I'm currently undertaking a project to build remote controlled shades from scratch. I currently have every piece figured out except I don't know know much about the motors involved in something like this. I am looking for suggestions on what type of motor to search for. I imagine I need a type that can go forward and back as well as stop when the shade is fully retracted. I don't know what to search for though.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the mechanism. Mine uses a linear actuator. The control system, often sold separately, will depend on the type of motor FYI.

Comment: Oooh! Please come back and post instructions and pics about what you did when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You need a gearmotor like the Dayton Model 2L003 .45 RPM 1/2800 hp 12VDC